# R Aggregating multiple rows into one, with missing values

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set in the format below

```
Date  Time  V1 V2 V3 ....

2018-02-18 09:51:47               NA              0.38               NA

2018-02-18 09:51:47               NA               NA                Quiet

2018-02-18 09:51:47               Normal               NA                NA

I want to merge the rows by Date and Time, and return

2018-02-18 09:51:47               Normal              0.38             Quiet
```

I tried aggregate function but it only returns the first row

```
aggregate(feb18[-grep("^(Date|Time)$", names(feb18))], feb18[c("Date", "Time")], FUN=function(x)  if(all(is.na(x))) NA else x[!is.na(x)][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Date, Time) %>%
  summarize(V1=max(V1, na.rm=T),
            V2=sum(V2, na.rm=T),
            V3=max(V3, na.rm=T))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 1 x 5
> # Groups:   Date [?]
>   Date       Time         V1        V2 V3   
>   <date>     <S4: Period> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
> 1 2018-02-18 9H 51M 47S   Normal 0.380 Quiet
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Since I have many variables I think it will be time consuming to list each variable. Is there a shortcut?

Comment: @math17 Standard shortcuts. You could make this logic into a function and apply it to all columns with `apply` or `sapply`. Or you could do the same vectorization thru data table.

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(.~Date+Time,df,function(x)x[!is.na(x)],na.action = identity)
        Date     Time     V1   V2    V3
1 2018-02-18 09:51:47 Normal 0.38 Quiet


  library(tidyverse)
   df%>%group_by(Date,Time)%>%
      summarise_all(~coalesce(!!!as.list(.)))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   Date [?]
  Date       Time     V1        V2 V3   
  <chr>      <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1 2018-02-18 09:51:47 Normal 0.380 Quiet
```

or

```
df%>%group_by(Date,Time)%>%
   summarise_all(~.x[!is.na(.x)])
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   Date [?]
  Date       Time     V1        V2 V3   
  <chr>      <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1 2018-02-18 09:51:47 Normal 0.380 Quiet
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried aggregate function but it gets rid of the NAs completely, which I don't want and all the text columns are replaced by numbers 1, 2 etc. It does not return Normal, Quiet entries

Comment: @math17 that is because your dataframe has factors instead of characters. Please convert the factor columns to characters then use aggregate. On the other hand you can use the `tidyverse` package

Comment: I changed factors to character still not working:( all values are converted to some random numbers, some entries are like 1, 1, 1.. couldn't install tidyverse on mac, I'll try again

Comment: @math17 when creating your dataframe, did you include stringsAsFactors=FALSE?? That is the thing you should include then run the aggregate code above

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = .(Date, Time)]
#         Date     Time     V1   V2    V3
#1: 2018-02-18 09:51:47 Normal 0.38 Quiet
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it but get this warning: Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(setDT(data2), , lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = .(Date,  :
  Item 5 of j's result for group 1 is zero length. This will be filled with 2 NAs to match the longest column in this result. Later groups may have a similar problem but only the first is reported to save filling the warning buffer.

Comment: @math17 This is based on your example.  Please provide an example that shows the problem

Comment: It is a huge data set with many columns (character and numeric). What I showed here was a makeup example. I'm attaching a picture of some part of the data.